# How to delete iptables rules added by kube-proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy

I want to manually delete iptables rules for debugging. 
I have several rules created by kube-proxy based on service `nettools`:

```
# kubectl get endpoints nettools
NAME       ENDPOINTS            AGE
nettools   172.16.27.138:7493   1h
```

And its iptables rules：

```
# iptables-save|grep nettools
-A KUBE-SEP-6DFMUWHMXOYMFWKG -s 172.16.27.138/32 -m comment --comment "default/nettools:web" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-6DFMUWHMXOYMFWKG -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nettools:web" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.27.138:7493
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.0.1.2/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nettools:web cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 7493 -j KUBE-SVC-INDS3KD6I5PFKUWF
-A KUBE-SVC-INDS3KD6I5PFKUWF -m comment --comment "default/nettools:web" -j KUBE-SEP-6DFMUWHMXOYMFWKG
```

However，I cannot delete those rules:

```
# iptables -D  KUBE-SVC-INDS3KD6I5PFKUWF -m comment --comment "default/nettools:web" -j KUBE-SEP-6DFMUWHMXOYMFWKG
iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `KUBE-SEP-6DFMUWHMXOYMFWKG':No such file or directory
# iptables -D KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.0.1.2/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nettools:web cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 7493 -j KUBE-SVC-INDS3KD6I5PFKUWF
iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `KUBE-SVC-INDS3KD6I5PFKUWF':No such file or directory
```

Comment: This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395271/274945

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple tables in play when dealing with `iptables`. `filter` table is the default if nothing is specified. The rules that you are trying to delete are part of the `nat` table.

Just add `-t nat` to your rules to delete those rules.

Example:

```
# iptables -t nat -D KUBE-SVC-INDS3KD6I5PFKUWF -m comment --comment "default/nettools:web" -j KUBE-SEP-6DFMUWHMXOYMFWKG
```